# Use System() with some dos commands issue:: QUERY.EXE is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c, windows, api, winapi

I am trying to execute "query user" inside this function system("query.exe user")

```
   int main()
   {
      system("query.exe user");
      system("c:\\windows\\system32\\query.exe");
      return 0;
   }
```

but the result is: 
query.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though 64-bit Windows only has a 64-bit version of `query.exe` so it will work only from the 64-bit version of the command interpreter.  Presumably your program is being built as a 32-bit application.

The **best** solution, if possible, is to not shell out at all, but to use the corresponding API directly.  Shelling out to an external program is common practice in UNIX but is discouraged in Windows.

However, if this is not possible:

If you only need to run on 64-bit systems, change the application to be 64-bit.

If you need to run on both 64-bit and 32-bit systems, you'll need to figure out which sort you're running on and behave accordingly at runtime.  You can use the IsWow64Process() API function to do this.

If you're on 32-bit Windows (or if the application is 64-bit) the command you used in the question should work as-is.  If you're a 32-bit application running on 64-bit Windows, change it to something like:

```
system("c:\\windows\\sysnative\\query.exe user");
```

In production code, you should look up the location of the Windows directory at runtime, e.g., using the GetWindowsDirectory() API function.

Comment: Thank you Harry, I tried to copy the query.exe from c:\windows\system32 to my application folder and it works.

Comment: If your code will only be running on your own systems, that's a reasonable work-around.  I'm not sure it would be sensible for third-party systems.

Comment: @eyyah Yes, that is definitely not the solution. Why won't you use the API for whatever you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Some commands are implemented internally by the command interpreter and not in separate executables. For such commands you need to execute the interpreter with appropriate arguments. For instance:

```
cmd /c query user
```

Other commands are implemented as executables. In which case `system` should find them. If the executable cannot be found either it does not exist or you are searching in the wrong place.

You need to work out how the command is implemented, and where any executable file resides.

Rather than shelling to an external process it would be idiomatic to use the appropriate API to obtain the information that you need.

Comment: Hi David, i tried 

system("cmd /c query user");

   but still same result : is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: So perhaps there is no such command on the target system. Perhaps you need to do some investigation on your system.

Comment: But when I open cmd.exe then run the command  "query user" it gives the full information

Comment: Sounds like an environmental problem. If system cannot execute cmd then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: I did mean the normal console in cmd.exe can execute "query user"  but in system("cmd /c query user")  does not work.

Comment: That sounds environmental

Comment: Looks like it's a bitness issue.  On my machine, at least, `query.exe` exists only in 64-bit flavour.

Answer (score 0):

I would never use `system` call, even the newer `CreateProcess`, `ShellExecute[Ex]` for such simple queries. Instead I would use the direct Win32 API for the same. For example [GetUserName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx) for finding current user name.

Please search for appropriate APIs instead of calling external programs, for ease of programming, proper control, security and speed. You can always search for API. You may use **Dependency Walker** to find what functions/DLLs might be used by Windows command. For instance, just open `Query.EXE` with Depends and find what functions are referred.